# How to get only <p> tag text including <span> tag

Tags: javascript, html

`<p class="aaa"> aaa <span class="bbb"> bbb </span> </p>`

I want to get only text 'aaa'

But `document.querySelector('p.aaa').innerText --> 'aaabbb'`

How do I get to text only 'aaa' ?

Comment: <span> is part of the paragraph, you would have to seperate the span and the paragraph. Only way I can think of is selecting the letters 'aaa' with index

Comment: Would you mind [accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) below. If i have helped and solved your question.

Answer (score 3):

This function will exclude the content for any child HTML elements from the selected element. It will also account for text values before and after child elements.

```js
function getText(selector) {
  return Array.from(document.querySelector(selector).childNodes)
    .reduce((text, node) => text + (node.wholeText || ''), '');
}

console.log(getText('p.aaa'));
```

```html
<p class="aaa"> aaa <span class="bbb"> bbb </span> ccc </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector('p.aaa').firstChild`

Will return the text you are asking for as is. Then you can `trim()` if need to remove extra spaces you may not need.

But I would also check to see if the value is simple text such as 'aaa' or a tag in case you might have other elements that satisfies the selector but whose first child could be an html element(tag) instead of simple text.

Answer (score 1):

you can use: `let text = document.querySelector('.aaa').childNodes[0].textContent.trim()`

Answer (score 0):

Use [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) and [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and using [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to get the text of `p` only.

Run snippet below.

```js
let text = document.querySelector('.aaa').childNodes[0].textContent.trim()

console.log(text) ///aaa
```

```html
<p class="aaa"> aaa <span class="bbb"> bbb </span> </p>
```

Comment: This won't work if there's another text node after the `<span>`.